# Django custom model save() method for a non-persisted attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django 4 custom model save() method, how do you pass a form non-persistent form value?

**For example:**

The model form below has the non-persistent field called `client_secret`.

```
class ClientModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    client_secret = forms.CharField(initial=generate_urlsafe_uuid)
```

This field will never be saved, it is auto-generated and will be required to make a hash for a persisted field in my model save() method.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_hash = models.BinaryField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Save override to hash the client secret on creation. """
        if self._state.adding:
            "GET THE CLIENT SECRET FROM THE FORM"
            client_hash = make_hash_key(client_secret)
            self.client_hash = client_hash
```

How do I get the client secret value from the form above code example? Is this the most appropriate approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call the super class' save method at the end like so:

```
super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For saving the form, you would need to add a model to the modelform's Meta class, and you would need to add the following logic into a view:

```
form = Form(request.METHOD)
if form.is_valid():
    uuid = form.instance.client_secret
    form.save()
```

Where form would look like:

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fields...
    class Meta:
        model = ClientModel
```

Highly recommend taking a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/)

### Edit

To get the logic into the model save, you could pass it into the kwargs of the save, `save(client_secret=client_secret)`, and then in the save method you could try:

```
self.field = kwargs.get('client_secret')
```

then when saving the form, as shown above, you could do

```
save(client_secret=uuid)
```

Comment: I don't have a problem saving the form, the issue is I want to logic in the "model" save, and the field does not exist on the model so I can't access it.

Comment: Edited my answer to fit your needs.